# Getting a top-left position of a tile inside a tileset

Tags: image, algorithm, tile

I have a tileset(a image full of other small images). And I wanna get one of those little images called tile so I can do something with it. I know the size of each tile(they're all the same size).
I have two equations:

```
x = (i % tiles_hor) * tile_h
y = (i % tiles_ver) * tile_w

x = (i % tiles_hor) * tile_w
y =  (i / tiles_hor) * tile_w
```

where **i** means the index of the tile i wanna get; 
**tiles_hor** is the number of tiles horizontally; 
**tiles_ver** is the number of tiles vertically; 
**tile_w** and **tile_h** is the width and height of each tile inside the tileset, respectively;

The tiles receive their index sequentially, like this:

```
01 02 03 04 05 
06 07 08 09 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

So each pair of digit it's the index of a tile inside the tileset.
Let's say I wanna get the tile 04(assuming the tiles have a 32x32 size each):
with the first equation:

x = (4 % 5) * 32 = 128. So it's x position inside the image is 128 
y = (4 % 5) * 32 = 0. So it's y inside the image is 0;

with the second equation: 
x = (4 % 5) * 32 = 128. So it's x position inside the image is 128 
y = (4 / 5) * 32 = 0. Here's is 0, cause we're first rounding the first expression for the closest minor number(i don't know if my expression is right. Please correct me if it's not).

Note that we're considering a perfect square tileset (in this case 5x5)

My question is:
The second works for most cases. The first stop working when there's no perfect squares tileset's and with a high height.
So what am I doing wrong there?

Also, how can be a equation that is letting out a really important value (tiles_ver and tile_h) can be right? What am I missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = ((i - 1) % tiles_hor) * tile_w
y = ((i - 1) / tiles_hor) * tile_h
```

Comment: what if instead of considering the tile_h, not consider at all, as it's done in the post. What that could bring me in a short or long-term?

Comment: if tile_w == tile_h, then you can just use tile_w. otherwise you need to consider them both.

Comment: Actually tile_w != tile_h. I wanted an example where not considering tile_h would mess up with the result. Can you see any?

Comment: sure, if tile_h is 1 and tile_w is 32, and if you want to calculate for tile 25, none of your equations will work

Comment: actually it will. Cause y =  (25 / 32) * 32 = 0 * 32 = 0

Comment: and why do you divide by 32? tiles_hor is 5.

Comment: i meant in the example you just gave in your previous comment.

Comment: using your second eq: y = (25 / 5) * 32 = 160. Using my eq: ((25 - 1) / 5) * 1 = 4.