# Tileset crop calculation C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, draw, crop, tile

So I have this problem with my tileset rendering. It's a little tricky to explain but i'll do my best.

Basicly what i do is i load these "tile numbers" from TMX files and they only represent the tileset number in the tileset. So if i use a tile that is on a row below the first one i only get the number. But i want both X and Y position to calculate where i would crop the image when i display it in my game.

So my array would look something like this,

```
1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,9,1,6,1,1
1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1
1,6,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,5,5,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1
```

Tileset:
http://puu.sh/9Tv2X/7938b6abf4.png

so when i render all the tiles in the first row in this tileset, numbers 1-4 (since the tileset is 4 tiles long) it works fine but anything past that would get cropped outside the image.

So for that i need the Y position to increase and to reset the X position everytime it goes outside the tileset width which is (32 * (tileNumber - 1)) but my brain cant figure out how to do this.

tile width and height is 32.

my code for drawing the tilset:

```
void TileMap::Draw()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mapVector.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < mapVector[i].size(); j++)
        {
            int tileY = 0;
            int tileX = mapVector[i][j] - 1;

            if (tileWidth * mapVector[i][j] > tilesetWidth)
            {
                //now what
            }



            if (mapVector[i][j] > 0)
            {
                tileSprite->SetPosition(j * tileWidth, i * tileHeight);
                tileSprite->SetTextureRect(tileX * tileWidth, tileY * tileHeight, 32, 32);
                tileSprite->Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's easy man... calculate how many tiles you can have in one line.. and use double loop for drawing them ;)

Comment: TL;DR
Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/11698131/26070 ?

Comment: Thanks mr_georg, the post helped me.